# Python suds - how to add nodes to header

Tags: python, soap, header, suds

I have to build soap request with this header structure:

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
<soapenv:Header>
    <com:session id="4223SE" xmlns:ns1="http://my_webservice/ws/common"/>
    <com:authToken id="32YEN232" xmlns:ns1="http://my_webservice/ws/common"/>
</soapenv:Header>
```

It works fine in SoapUI but not in my Python script.

I don't know how to add child nodes **session** and **authToken** and attributes for them to my header.

When I trying to call:

```
suds_client= suds.client.Client(url)
```

or sth. like this:

```
suds_client = suds.client.Client(url, headers={'session': {id:'value'}})
```

every time I get error:

```
message '(u'executeServiceRequestMsg', u'http://my_webservice/ws/broker')' has
not part named 'session'
```

I had tried thousands of combinations of structure passed in my client init, but it won't work, so I decided to ask here for your help. It's my first post, so sorry in advance if I have done sth. wrong.